# I want to check name of that particular company's shift exist or not?

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have many to many relationship and I'm trying to check this company's shift name already exist or not in database.

relation is below.

```
public function shifts()
{

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Shift');

}

public function companies()
{

      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Company');

}
```

Comment: Whats the question, where is your code, what have you tried? You write, we help, we dont write code for you.

Answer (score 2):

you can check it with like below:

```
$company = Company::find(id)->with('shifts')->where('shiftname','shiftname')->get();
```

it will return record or null.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it with

```
$company = Company::find(1);

$company->shifts()->where('shift_name', "yourShiftName")->get();
```